# Error using randint(), 'TypeError: must be str not int'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's my code, which executes a simple number guessing game:

```
i = 1
lower = input('Enter the lower range: ')
upper = input('Enter the upper range: ')
from random import randint
answer = randint(lower, upper)
guess = input("What's the number? ")
while guess != answer:
    if ~(guess in range(lower, upper)):
        print('Your guess must be in the range', lower, 'to', upper)
        i = i - 1
    elif guess < answer:
        print('Too low!')
    elif guess > answer:
        print('Too  high!')
    guess = input("What's the number? ")
    i = i + 1
print('Congrats! You correctly guessed the number to be ', answer, '! It took you ', i, ' tries.', sep='')
```

When I try to run it, the command prompt gives me the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\random.py", line 220, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

*EDIT*: Thanks for the solutions, changing `input(...)` to `int(input(...))` fixed my code. I'll also add that line 8 also contains an error. It should be: `if not (guess in range(lower, upper + 1)):`.

Comment: Hint: in python 3 (unlike python 2), input returns a string ... doing randint('1','5') returns an error similar to what you got (I don't have python3 handy)... you want to do upper = int(input("....")) and likewise for lower

Comment: This `if ~(guess in range(lower, upper)):` is a very unusual usage of the `~` operator. It's better written as `if guess not in range(lower, upper):` or much simpler as `if lower <= guess < upper:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the input to integer first:

```
lower = int(input('Enter the lower range: '))
upper = int(input('Enter the upper range: '))
```

To explain the error: The error message is a bit misleading since it says you need `str` instead of `int` and not the other way around. However, it comes from the fact that before the internal `randrange` function is executed, `b` is incremented, so you have for example `'10'+1` and that generates this error.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking your "numbers" from the `input()` function.

The `input()` is coming to you as a string. You need to convert it to numeric form using `int(lower)` before the values to `randint()`.

(The error stems from the `b+1` - `randint` is trying to do addition, but adding to a string is defined as concatenation, which requires two strings.)